# Unity3D - Cancel a build process (Windows, Unity 5)

Tags: unity, ios, windows

I accidently pressed build for iOS and just realized that it might take a few hours to build the project. I tried to kill the unity process in the task manager, but on next start up unity instantly starts to build it again. Is there any option to cancel the build?

Answer (score 1):

There is a cross button right next to build loading bar.
[image: As shown in the picture]

Comment: You are on Mac right? I dont see any button there...

Comment: Strange you are using unity 5 option, so it should be there! any how this link might help you: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/308245/how-do-i-stoppausebreak-a-build-automatically-on-e.html